# Making division scrollable when the keyboard pops up

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app

I have a form and I am creating a tizen app.When the key board comes up,Two fields are getting covered by the keyboard.I need to make the whole division scrollable when the keyboard pops up.I've tried to use the overflow,But it isn't working.

```
<body>
<div id="headerdiv">
    ADD YOUR VEHICLE


enter code here
</div>
<div id=form>
textarea class="manufacturer" cols="40"  rows="1"  placeholder="Manufacturer*"></textarea>
<textarea class="model" cols="40"  rows="1"  placeholder="Model*"></textarea>
 <span id=date_purch>Date of Purchase</span>
<p>
<input class="inputDate" id="inputDate" value="10/28/2015" readonly/>

  <span id=reg_numb>Registration Number</span>
<textarea class="number" cols="40"  rows="1"  placeholder="AA 00 AA 0000* ">   </textarea>
<span id=front_pres>Tyre Pressure:Front</span>
<textarea class="front" cols="40"  rows="1"  placeholder="32 PSI*"></textarea>
<span id=rear_pres>Tyre Pressure:Rear</span>
<textarea class="rear" cols="40"  rows="1"  placeholder="32 PSI*"></textarea> 
</div>

<button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="cancel" onclick="back()">Cancel</div>

</body>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJTJb.png)

The keyboard hides the tyre pressure fields.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to look into the following link.
https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/tizen-features/ime-application

In particular,
setKeyboardSizes(portraitWidth, portraitHeight, landscapeWidth, landscapeHeight)

Lets you set the dimensions of your keyboard.

Comment: But is there anyway to make the divisio scrollable?Because setting the keyboard width will affect the layout on different resolution devices since I've used pixels for placing the fields since using percentage tends to make the fields change position when keyboard popps up

Comment: <div id="" style="overflow:auto; height:400px;"> - doesn't work ?